Zhang's result might leave the twin prime conjecture susceptible to a sort-of (reverse) proof-by-induction. Closeness of various gap formulas.
I can prove that the following function $Z_{h,n}: \Bbb{N}\to \Bbb{N}$ counts exactly the number of $2h$-separated prime pair (averages) in the Eratosthenes interval $[p_n + h + 1, x]$ for any $x \in [p_n + h + 1, p_{n+1}^2 - h - 1]$ (i.e. for sufficiently large $n\geq 1$, for each fixed $h \geq 1$).
$$
Z_{h,n}(g) = \sum_{d\ \mid\ p_n\#}\frac{(-1)^{\omega(d)}}{2^{\omega(d,h) - [2\mid (d,h)]}}\sum_{r^2 = 1 \mod d}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{g - rh}{d} \right\rfloor- \left\lfloor \frac{p_n + h - rh}{d}\right\rfloor \right)
$$
where $(d,h) := \gcd(d,h), \omega(d,h) := \omega(\gcd(d,h))$ and $[2 \mid (d,h)] := \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } 2 \mid \gcd(d,h) \\ 0 \text{ otherwise }.\end{cases}$.
The solution residues $r$ to $r^2 = 1 \mod d$ may be chosen to be any integer such $r' = r \pmod d$ !!!
Here is some verification code if you don't trust this bold statement:
from sympy import *

init_printing()

def actual_count(k, n, x):
    c = 0
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    for a in range(prime(n)+k + 1, x+1):        
        if isprime(a-k) and isprime(a+k):
            c += 1
            
    return c

def abs_is_prime_or_1(q):
    q = abs(q)
    return q == 1 or isprime(q) 

def formula(k, n, x):
    P = primorial(n)
    S = 0
    #b = prime(n+1) ** 2 - k - 1
    
    #for y in range(0, b+1):
        #if (y - k in {-1, 1} and isprime(y+k)) or \
           #(y + k in {-1, 1} and isprime(y-k)):
            #S -= 1
            
    #if k == 1 or (isprime(k) and k not in range(2, prime(n)+1)):
        #S -= 1    
                        
    for d in divisors(P):
        T = 0
        
        for r in range(d):
            if (r ** 2 - 1 ** 2) % d == 0:
                T += floor((x-r*k)/d) + floor(r*k/d)
                
        S += (-1) ** primeomega(d) * T / 2 ** (primeomega(gcd(d, k)) - (1 if gcd(d, k) % 2 == 0 else 0))
        
    return S
    

N = 8

for k in range(1, N):
    for n in range(1, N):    
        if prime(n) + k + 1 <= prime(n+1) ** 2 - k - 1:            
            xk = prime(n+1) ** 2 - k - 1
            #x1 = prime(n+1) ** 2 - 2
            x1 = xk
            f1 = formula(1, n, x1) - formula(1, n, prime(n) + 1)
            fk = formula(k, n, xk) - formula(k, n, prime(n) + k)
            ck = actual_count(k, n, xk)
            c1 = actual_count(1, n, x1)
            assert fk == ck
            print(f'@k={k},n={n},fk({xk})={fk};{ck} actual. f1({x1})={f1};{c1} actual.')

Which prints:
@k=1,n=1,fk(7)=2;2 actual. f1(7)=2;2 actual.
@k=1,n=2,fk(23)=3;3 actual. f1(23)=3;3 actual.
@k=1,n=3,fk(47)=4;4 actual. f1(47)=4;4 actual.
@k=1,n=4,fk(119)=8;8 actual. f1(119)=8;8 actual.
@k=1,n=5,fk(167)=9;9 actual. f1(167)=9;9 actual.
@k=1,n=6,fk(287)=16;16 actual. f1(287)=16;16 actual.
@k=1,n=7,fk(359)=17;17 actual. f1(359)=17;17 actual.
@k=2,n=1,fk(6)=1;1 actual. f1(6)=2;2 actual.
@k=2,n=2,fk(22)=3;3 actual. f1(22)=3;3 actual.
@k=2,n=3,fk(46)=5;5 actual. f1(46)=4;4 actual.
@k=2,n=4,fk(118)=9;9 actual. f1(118)=8;8 actual.
@k=2,n=5,fk(166)=11;11 actual. f1(166)=9;9 actual.
@k=2,n=6,fk(286)=14;14 actual. f1(286)=16;16 actual.
@k=2,n=7,fk(358)=17;17 actual. f1(358)=17;17 actual.
@k=3,n=2,fk(21)=5;5 actual. f1(21)=3;3 actual.
@k=3,n=3,fk(45)=8;8 actual. f1(45)=4;4 actual.
@k=3,n=4,fk(117)=17;17 actual. f1(117)=8;8 actual.
@k=3,n=5,fk(165)=19;19 actual. f1(165)=9;9 actual.
@k=3,n=6,fk(285)=30;30 actual. f1(285)=16;16 actual.
@k=3,n=7,fk(357)=34;34 actual. f1(357)=17;17 actual.
@k=4,n=2,fk(20)=2;2 actual. f1(20)=3;3 actual.
@k=4,n=3,fk(44)=3;3 actual. f1(44)=4;4 actual.
@k=4,n=4,fk(116)=8;8 actual. f1(116)=8;8 actual.
@k=4,n=5,fk(164)=9;9 actual. f1(164)=9;9 actual.
@k=4,n=6,fk(284)=14;14 actual. f1(284)=16;16 actual.
......

In 2013, Yitang Zhang proved that $Z_{h, n}(g)$ is infinitely often nonzero (as $n$ increases) for some fixed $h \lt \frac{7\times 10^6}{2}$.  James Maynard and a Polymath project et al lowered this to $h \lt \frac{ 246}{2} = 123$.
Here is the Wikipedia section on that.

Now this won't prove twin prime conjecture, but take this as a sample of what you could do with the $Z_{h,n}(g)$ formula inductively.
Assume that there exists some $h \lt 123$ of the form $h =p_{n+1}$ (a prime  number)  for some $n \geq 1$ such that Zhang's result says there's infinitely many $2h$-separated prime pairs.
Then clearly $\gcd(p_n\#, h) = 1$, which makes the formula at $h = p_{n+1}$ look extremely similar to the formula at $h = 1$.  Using the first formula at the start of this post:
$$
Z_{p_{n+1},n}(g) = \sum_{d\ \mid\ p_n\#}\frac{(-1)^{\omega(d)}}{2^{\omega(d,h) - [2\mid (d,p_{n+1})]}}\sum_{r^2 = 1 \mod d}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{g - rp_{n+1}}{d} \right\rfloor- \left\lfloor \frac{p_n + p_{n+1} - rp_{n+1}}{d}\right\rfloor \right) \\ \ \\
\  =  \sum_{d\ \mid\ p_n\#}(-1)^{\omega(d)}\sum_{r^2 = 1 \mod d}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{g - rp_{n+1}}{d} \right\rfloor- \left\lfloor \frac{p_n + p_{n+1} - rp_{n+1}}{d}\right\rfloor \right) \\
$$
Now look closer at the inner summation.  It is a sum over a group!  Namely $G_d = \{\overline{r} \in \Bbb{Z}/d : \overline{r}^2 = 1 \mod d \} \leqslant (\Bbb{Z}/d)^{\times}$.  And as we all know from group theory that left-multiplication by a unit (in this case $p_{n+1}$) will result an element of $(\Bbb{Z}/d)^{\times}/ G_d$ namely $p_{n+1}G$.  Now I don't know how  I'd make use of this other than fixing $n$ and summing over various fixed values of $h =$ a unit of $(\Bbb{Z}/d)^{\times}$.

Here's another trick.  Fix $n$ and let $h =$ a residue of a unit of $G_{p_n\#} = \{ \overline{r} \in \Bbb{Z}/p_n\# : r^2 = 1 \mod p_n\#\}$.  Then clearly $hr$ is an element of $G_d$ for every $d$ dividing $p_n\#$ (in the involved sums).
Therefore, in that case, for each $d \mid p_n\#$ we have that $hG_d = G_d$ as left-multiplication by an element of a group produces the same group!
Hence,
$$
h^2 = 1 \mod p_n\# \implies \\ \ \\
Z_{h,n}(g) = \sum_{d\ \mid\ p_n\#}(-1)^{\omega(d)}\sum_{r^2 = 1 \mod d}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{g - rh}{d} \right\rfloor- \left\lfloor \frac{p_n + h - rh}{d}\right\rfloor \right) \\
\ = \sum_{d\ \mid \ p_n\#}(-1)^{\omega(d)}\sum_{r^2 = 1 \mod d}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{g - r}{d} \right\rfloor- \left\lfloor \frac{p_n + h - r}{d}\right\rfloor \right)
$$
So that $Z_{h,n}(g) - Z_{1,n}(g)   = \dots$ the terms involving $g$ cancel!  We get:
$$
Z_{h,n}(g) - Z_{1,n}(g)  = \sum_{d\ \mid\ p_n\#}(-1)^{\omega(d)}\sum_{r^2 = 1 \mod d}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{p_n + h - r}{d}\right\rfloor  - \left\lfloor\frac{p_n + 1  - r}{d} \right\rfloor \right)
$$
Now a finite number of twin primes implies that $Z_{1,n}(g) = 0$ for all $g \in [0, p_{n+1}^2 - 2]$, for sufficiently lare $n \geq n_0 \in \Bbb{N}$.
Which would force $Z_{h,n}(g)$ to be independent of $g$, indeed it would appear to be a constant, for all $n \geq n_0$.  But this is impossible as $\lim_{g \to \infty} Z_{h,n}(g) = \infty$ is easy to prove for any $h,n\geq 1$ (this fact does not rely on Zhang's result).

Question.  The question becomes how can we use the last fact + Zhang's result as a kind of "reverse proof-by-induction base step"?

This feels interesting. I’ll leave a comment and see if anyone can verify OP’s claims.

@JonathanHuang which claim do you find most hard to believe?  And I'll expand the post with a proof or two.

I think the second term in the inner summation might have to be a ceiling instead of a floor (from my experience deriving it), but that's okay, has no effect on any of the above statements.

My limit statement isn't quite right.  It should be that $Z_{h,n}(g=p_{n+1}^2 - h - 1)=$ independent of $g$ so that $0 \geq  Z_{h,n}(0) = Z_{h,n}(p_{n+1}^2 -h-1) =$ a positive number i.o.  So a contradiction.  Have to do it this way as $Z_{1,n}(g) = 0$ only for $g \in [0, \dots, p_{n+1}^2 - 2]$!  So it's still correct, modulo the limit stuff.

You can ask a Same question on Math overflow
